# SwiftUI: In SplitView, how can I detect if the master view is visible?

Tags: swiftui, master-detail, splitview

When SwiftUI creates a SplitView, it adds a toolbar button that hides/shows the Master view. How can I detect this change so that I can resize the font in the detail screen and use all the space optimally?

I've tried using .onChange with geometry but can't seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iOS 16 you can use `NavigationSplitView` with `NavigationSplitViewVisibility`

Example:

```
struct MySplitView: View {
    @State private var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all
    
    var bothAreShown: Bool { columnVisibility != .detailOnly }
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            Text("Master Column")
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail Column")
            Text(bothAreShown ? "Both are shown" : "Just detail shown")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinkering for a while on this I got to this solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var isOpen = true

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            Text("Primary")
                .onUIKitAppear {
                    isOpen.toggle()
                }
                .onAppear{
                print("hello")
                    isOpen.toggle()
                }
                .onDisappear{
                    isOpen.toggle()
                    print("hello: bye")
                }
       .navigationTitle("options")
        }
        Text("Secondary").font(isOpen ? .body : .title)

    }.navigationViewStyle(.columns)
}


}
```

The onUIKitAppear is a custom `extension` suggested by apple to be only executed once the view has been presented to the user https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655338?page=2

```
  struct UIKitAppear: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
     let action: () -> Void
     
     func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIAppearViewController {
        let vc = UIAppearViewController()
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
     }
     
     func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(action: self.action)
     }
     
     func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIAppearViewController, context: Context) {}
     
     class Coordinator: ActionRepresentable {
        var action: () -> Void
        init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
              self.action = action
        }
        func remoteAction() {
              action()
        }
     }
  }

  protocol ActionRepresentable: AnyObject {
     func remoteAction()
  }

  class UIAppearViewController: UIViewController {
     weak var delegate: ActionRepresentable?
     var savedView: UIView?
     
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.savedView = UILabel()
        
        if let _view = self.savedView {
              view.addSubview(_view)
        }
     }
     
     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.remoteAction()
     }
     
     override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        savedView?.removeFromSuperview()
     }
  }

  public extension View {
     
     func onUIKitAppear(_ perform: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(UIKitAppear(action: perform))
     }
  }
```

[image]